# What to make of this suggested edit by an anonymous user?

Tags: discussion

I got [this suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/8435531) from an anonymous user.

This does not sound like something a responsible SO user would do. I am not sure what could be the objective of such suggestions. Any sane SO user would know that this will be rejected. Could this be the work of a bot? Should we be concerned?

Comment: It was clearly some sort of spam attempt. Whether it was a bot or not isn't evident. In what way should *we* be concerned? If it was a bot, it's something the SE staff should possibly be concerned about, but I personally wouldn't be; other than watching for those sorts of posts, there's little I can do about them.

Comment: @KenWhite, I don't know whether we should be concerned about it. Maybe not.

Comment: The edit was rejected so I wouldn't be concerned about it. If it had been approved, then there would be a problem but it's so obviously a bad edit I can't imagine anyone approving it.

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. *We* (as in SE users) have nothing to be concerned about, because other than rejecting this type of edit there's nothing we can do. SE developers may need to be concerned.

Comment: @KenWhite, You are answering "no" to my question "Should we be concerned?". That's good enough for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spam/abusive edits happen from time to time by anonymous users. Just reject them. Nothing to be concerned about. Maybe if you start seeing it happen very frequently (like 25 times a week) you could start a new question about it to see if something more could be done.